# Windows erases content of JFrame when overlapping

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, paintcomponent

I create and display a window using JFrame having set it just very basic properties.

```
public FrameVertices( String sTitle, Graph mMap, int iMul ) {
    super( sTitle );

    setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    setSize ( 300, 300 );
    setLocation ( 600, 300 );
    setVisible ( true);

    this.iMul = iMul;
    this.gGraph = mMap;
}
```

Then I paint something inside the window using **paint()** method.

The problem is that when some other windows cover my `JFrame` and then uncover it, the content of the `JFrame` is not repainted - unless I resize or min/max the `JFrame`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Your missing more code that could possibly show us where your error is. Consider creating a *small* compilable and runnable program that we can run and that would demonstrate for us your problem. As an aside, you should almost never draw directly in a top-level Swing window but instead should draw in the paintComponent method of a JComponent such as a JPanel.

Comment: Please also show the `paint()` method code or as HFOE said create an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not good practice to paint directly to a `JFrame`. A better approach is to override `paintComponent()` in a `JPanel`  and add the `JPanel`  to the `JFrame`:

Test.java:

```
public class Test extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
           new Test().createUI();
          }
       });

    }

  void createUI() {

             setSize(500,500);
             getContentPane().add(new MyPanel());
             setVisible(true);      
       }
}
```

MyPanel.java:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    @override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      //paint what you want here
      g.drawString("Hello world",250,250);
    }
}
```

However if you must, I'd suggest adding a Window `FocusListener` and call `repaint()` on the `JFrame` instance when its brought into focus: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html

via the method `windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e)` or `windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e)` or `windowActivated(WindowEvent e)` calling `repaint()` in 1 of these methods will then call the `paint()` method.

Comment: Drawing on JPanel using paintComponent was the solution. It seems that paint() on JFrame is executed when you resize the window or min/max it - not when other windows cover it and erase the content. In turn - paintComponent is fired and repaints the content.

Comment: @Protechnologia.pl: Not only that, but you gain the advantage of Swing's double buffering when you do this. 1+.

Comment: I've noticed a small slip in your first snippet. You call a non-static methods from a static method Main (to be precise - from an inner class inside a static method Main). If I'm right - in Main, you should at first create an instance of Test class, then you would be able to call those methods on it.

Comment: @Protechnologia.pl thank you updated code. was doing it by head :P

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by David in the earlier answer , that's not a good way to go about Swing stuff , but if you have to, or somehow want to do so , u might want to use the `WindowListener` Interface ( or `WindowAdapter` class, in case u want to simplify the task of overriding methods ) and use the `windowActivated` or `windowDeactivated` functions to somehow call the `repaint()` method. 
here's docs : [WindowListener#windowDeactivated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowDeactivated%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29)

EDIT:
From the given  code example,seems you've extended the `JFrame` class, so your only option is implementing the `WindowListener` Interface.

Comment: No, the best option is not to extend JFrame and not to draw directl in the JFrame.

Comment: Yes,you're totally right, and well i just pointed a way out in case there's some emphasis on solving the problem 'that' way.